# Magento 2 - Get color attribute based on its size attribute of product

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, product-attribute

I am trying to get the color attribute based on the size attribute.

```
public function getSize($product)
{
    $_attributes = $this->getAllowAttributes();
    $result = array();
    foreach ($_attributes as $_attribute){
         $result[] = $_attribute->getProductAttribute()->getAttributeCode();
    }
    $size = $product->getResource()->getAttribute($result[0])->getFrontend()->getValue($product);
    if ($size == "No" || is_null($size)) {
        $size = '';
    }

    return $size;
}
```

This will display size attribute of product. But I want to display its related color like this:
Size-1 / Color-1
Size-1 / Color-2
Size-1 / Color-3
Size-1 / Color-4
Size-2 / Color-1
Size-2 / Color-2
Size-2 / Color-3
Size-2 / Color-4
Size-3 / Color-1
Size-3 / Color-2
Size-3 / Color-3
Size-3 / Color-4

My view page looks like:

```
<tr>
    <td class="option"><span class="product-option"><?= $block->escapeHtml($block->getSize($product)); ?></span></td>
    <?php //foreach ($_attributes as $_attribute): ?>
    <?php if ($product->isAvailable()): ?>
        <td class="status"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('In stock') ?></td>
    <?php else: ?>
        <td class="status"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Out of stock') ?><a href="#" class="restock-nortify" title="商品入荷のお知らせを受け取る">再入荷通知</a></td>
    <?php endif; ?>
</tr>
```

Is there any method to get like this?

Thanks in advance.